# How to remove unremovable permissions

Tags: permissions, android-auto

Samsung Galaxy S23.

How do I remove permissions from Android Auto to Change Network Connectivity. I can see the permission is assigned when I go to `Settings` > `Apps` > `Android Auto` > `Permissions` > `Show All Permissions`  (from the top right menu).

I want to remove this permission because Android Auto makes the wrong decisions about when Bluetooth and wifi should be enabled.

Please don't suggest any "you're asking the wrong question" kind of answers. I am a power user and know what and why I want to do this, and second-guessing motivations and needs is unnecessary, and unhelpful.

Comment: It would appear that you can't. On mine, it never fiddles with network connection.Are you implying that it alters them on your phone?

Comment: @robert as the question states,  "Android auto makes the wrong decisions about when Bluetooth and wifi should be enabled".

Comment: @RohitGupta yes. I disabled Bluetooth, and android auto turned it back in a moment later.  A Google search shows that this is a common issue across multiple versions of Android.

Comment: Looks like those are not runtime permissions, so they can't be disabled normally. Related but old: [Android Lollipop/Marshmallow full granular control of system app permissions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/163739/44325). Otherwise, AppOps (through [PermissionManagerX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX?tab=readme-ov-file) by our trusted member Irfan Latif) might help.